# ocr using a command line tool

Tags: command-line, numbers, ocr

I'm looking for a windows command line tool that does OCR. Specifically I'm trying to extract the number from this image:
http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/6075/wantocr.png

I've tried tesseract and found it quite poor imho. Perhaps it needs settings that I'm not aware of. I've tried a few others and they too were pretty poxy. Some of the online ones were quite good but I really need it to be a command line.

I would really appreciate posts that accurately extract the number from the image in the link above.

many thanks,
Fidel

p.s. I could do some very simple image processing like converting it to blank and white etc.

Comment: Thanks FUZxxl, will do. I'm still interested in the results here because a lot of programmers have worked with OCR and the program I want to call this command line from will be C#. But thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Aquaforest's [Tiff Junction Professional](http://www.aquaforest.com/en/merge_tiff_junction.asp) (Windows only)
- [Intelliant OCR](http://www.intelliant.fr/en/ocr-document-management-systems-shareware.php) (Command line)
- ABBYY FineReader ([Linux only CLI](http://www.ocr4linux.com/en%3astart))

Answer (score 1):

As some of the links here were rotten after the years: I just stumbled across this topic and found Tesseract to be quite good nowadays!
It's FOSS, in constant development and now on version 4.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

[installation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki#installation) links to binaries for [Windows](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki#tesseract-at-ub-mannheim) as well. And then

```
tesseract image_name.png out.txt
```

Yielded some useful things already!